# JAVA design a factory for enum's

Tags: java, enums, factory

Decide on a set of enum's of similar structure, dynamically based on a parameter.

example :

```
public enum StateUS {
 CALIFORNIA(Sacramento,...)
 private String capital;
 ...
}

public enum StateIN {
 KARNATAKA(Bangalore,...)
 private String capital;
 ...
}

public enum Countries {
US, IN
}

// in a different class
public <> getStates(Countries country){
// to return Country.US.equals(country) ?  StateUS : StateIN 
// so the return enum class can be used for business logic.
}
```

Based on the value of enum `Countries`, need to decide whether to use `StateUS` or `StateIN`.

what's the best way to implement the same using enum's ? Can a factory class be implemented to decide on enum ?

Solution I can think of is to convert enum's into classes and create a factory class. But this is a tedious procedure and too much of boiler code to get enum functionalities (ex : comparisons).

Comment: What's your use case? Notice that enums are classes. In your case, when you want to return either `StateUS` or `StateIN` it actually means that you want to return `Class<? extends Enum>`, as those two cannot be thought of in any other way. Is that really what you want?

Comment: What are you actually wanting to return? A list of states, or the type (i.e., StateUS or StateIN)?

Comment: @MirekPluta yes I want to return the class, can we get the instance of enum from the class. So that we can use the reference as regular enum holder. ex : getStates(US).valueOf("california") or getStates(US).doSomething() (defined within Enum)

Comment: @ernest_k Enum type

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it. You would need to add a `State` interface:

```java
public interface State {
    String getCapital();
}
```

Then make both `StateIN` and `StateUS` implement such an Interface:

```java
public enum StateIN implements State {
    KARNATAKA("Bangalore");

    private String capital;

    StateIN(String capital) {
        this.capital = capital;
    }

    @Override
    public String getCapital() {
        return capital;
    }
}
```

```java
public enum StateUS implements State {
    CALIFORNIA("Sacramento");

    private String capital;

    StateUS(String capital) {
        this.capital = capital;
    }

    @Override
    public String getCapital() {
        return capital;
    }
}
```

And in your `Countries` enum you would need to take advantage of the `State` interface to allow the following:

```java
public enum Countries {
    IN(Arrays.asList(StateIN.values())),
    US(Arrays.asList(StateUS.values()));

    private List<? extends State> states;

    Countries(List<? extends State> states) {
        this.states = states;
    }

    public List<? extends State> getStates() {
        return states;
    }
}
```

And now you can implement your `getStates(Countries country)` as you would like to have it:

```java
public static List<? extends State> getStates(Countries country){
    return country.getStates();
}
```

Below is an example so that you can check that this actually works:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("States");
    System.out.println("IN: " + getStates(Countries.IN));
    System.out.println("US: " + getStates(Countries.US));
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("States Capital");
    System.out.println("IN: " + getStates(Countries.IN).stream().map(State::getCapital).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    System.out.println("US: " + getStates(Countries.US).stream().map(State::getCapital).collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to have enum type handler as the response of getStates() functions. 
```public enum Countries {
    IN(StateIN),
    US(StateUS);

    private Class<? extends Enum<?>> states;

    Countries(Class<? extends Enum<?>>  states) {
        this.states = states;
    }

    public Class<? extends Enum<?>>  getStates() {
        return states;
    }
}```

with `Class<? extends Enum<?>> getStates(Country country)`
this would help to access any static methods defined in `States<>` enum as well. But is it possible to get Enum type reference from Class object ?better approach ?

Comment: I have no better approach in my mind. My suggestion is as good as it gets in my opinion.